# How to add the 'id' of a django model in a django form

Tags: django

So I want to associate a comment with a `transfernews` and so I have to get the `transfernews id` and auto populate the `transfernews id` in the `transfernews` field of my comment form. But currently in my comment form, it is showing the `transfernews` field and it is letting my users select which `transfernews` to comment on. How can I change my code so that my view fetches the `transfernews id` and assigns it to the `transfernews` field of my `comment form` and hides it from my users.

My models.py:

```
class Transfernews(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    player_image = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    player_description = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transfernews = models.ForeignKey(Transfernews, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.transfernews.player_name, self.user.username)
```

My forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body', 'transfernews')
```

My views.py:

```
def transfer_targets(request):
    transfernews = Transfernews.objects.all()
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.user = request.user
        new_comment.save()
        return redirect(request.path_info)
    return render(request, 'transfernews.html', {'transfernews': transfernews, 'form': form})
```

My transfernews.html:

```
<h2>Comments...</h2>

{% if not transfer.comments.all %}
No comments Yet...
{% else %}
{% for comment in transfer.comments.all %}
<strong>
    {{ comment.user.username }} - {{ comment.date_added }}
</strong>
<br/>
{{ comment.body }}
<br/><br/>

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<hr>
<div>Comment and let us know your thoughts</div>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm shadow-none" type="submit">Post comment</button>
    
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm ml-1 shadow-none" type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove 'transfernews' from from

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body', 'transfernews')
```

That should remove/hide it from my users.

2. `How can I change my code so that my view fetches the transfernews id and assigns it to the transfernews field of my comment form'

Normally Django doesn't do that.

Normal way is setting like  `new_comment.user = request.user`.

1. get 'Transfernews' id from url/ post form field

```
1] urls > comments/post/id_of_transfernews
or
2] request.POST.get['tf_id']
```

2. `tf=Transfernews.objects.filter(id=id_from_url)`
3. 

```
new_comment = form. Save(commit=False)
new_comment.user = request. User
new_comment.transfernews = tf
new_comment.save()
```